# how to get JSON data from Rapid API using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I try to get JSON data from API but no luck,  any help regarding this matter what is wrong. Here is my code.

```
    <?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://coronavirus-monitor.p.rapidapi.com/coronavirus/latest_stat_by_country.php?country=pakistan",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-rapidapi-host: coronavirus-monitor.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key: d1a16d6185msh28b0a37babf5f15p141020jsn35571bfb92c9"),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
   $err = curl_error($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
   else {
   echo $response->latest_stat_by_country[0]->country_name . "</br>";
   echo $response->latest_stat_by_country[0]->total_cases . "</br>";
   echo $response->latest_stat_by_country[0]->new_cases . "</br>";
   echo $response->latest_stat_by_country[0]->active_cases . "</br>";
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  An empty response?  A response that isn't JSON?  If an error, which line is it on?  All these things are important for anybody to be able to help you.  Also, you appear to have included a private API key in this post.  You should probably revoke it immediately and get a new one that you keep secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the `$response` as if it were an array, but it isn't, it's JSON. You need to `json_decode($response)` first:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://coronavirus-monitor.p.rapidapi.com/coronavirus/latest_stat_by_country.php?country=pakistan",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-rapidapi-host: coronavirus-monitor.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key: d1a16d6185msh28b0a37babf5f15p141020jsn35571bfb92c9"),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    // Changes made here:
    $data = json_decode($response);
    echo $data->latest_stat_by_country[0]->country_name . "</br>";
    echo $data->latest_stat_by_country[0]->total_cases . "</br>";
    echo $data->latest_stat_by_country[0]->new_cases . "</br>";
    echo $data->latest_stat_by_country[0]->active_cases . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: kerbholz  Thanks

Comment: kerbholz problem solved and marked as helpful

Comment: Thanks, glad it works

Comment: hello @kerbholz is there any way to populate above json data dynamically to html table using php, i have 199 countries

Comment: There certainly is, but that would be the topic for another question